# Decomposition of the Schwartz space as a representation for the orthogonal group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, schwartz-distributions, orthogonal-groups

The Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is naturally a $O_n(\mathbb{R})$-representation. I'm assuming that this is a relatively well-behaved representation among the infinite-dimensional ones and that someone has already thought through the decomposition of this representation into irreducibles in a suitable, infinite-dimensional sense.

My naive conjecture would be that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a specific completion of the sum over most/all irreducibles of $O_n$; probably a subspace like $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cdot e^{-\|x\|^2}$ gets completed and probably the completion step works something like the rapidly decreasing sequences space $\mathcal{s}(\mathbb{N}^n)$.

Is this true? Can you point me to a citable resource for this?

Additionally I'm looking for a description of how the decomposition into irreducibles plays with the Fourier transform and the multiplication on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Well, the decomposition of $L^2(S^{n - 1})$ as a $\mathrm{O}(n)$-module is simply the theory of spherical harmonics. You can extend these radially via a Gaussian. With regards to your last question, see Hecke's identity for homogeneous harmonic polynomials; it's somewhere in Stein and Weiss.